# Android Soft Keyboard Keys Layout

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to build an Android Soft keyboard application using avail code at

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

I want to rounded key like iPhone.

please suggest me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) drawables for backgrounds.